# C# XNA rectangle collision detecting from which side

Tags: c#, xna, collision

I have a player rectangle and a wall rectangle.  I'm trying to determine from which side the player hit the wall.

For example, if the player hit the wall from his left side, then the player can't keep going left through the wall but can go up, down or right.

How can I determine from which side the player hit the wall?

Comment: If it's a C# question, you'd better share a small and explicit C# code snippet and ask your question.

Comment: Not all questions require source code, especially ones about general programming theory.  I don't think adding a code snippet would do anything at all to improve this question.  that being said, this probably doesn't need the C# tag, as there is nothing language specific about it.

Comment: Removed C# tag as the question is not C# language specific. Grammar correction for clarity. I think in your last statement you mean to say user can move other side but the left. There was a typo (cant was used).

Answer (score 0):

Before you update the player's position and rectangle, keep a record of the old rectangle so it can be compared to the new position. For example:

```
// Keep a record of old rectangle
Rectangle oldPos = player.Rectangle;

// Update player position and rectangle here

// Check for collision
if (player.Rectangle.Intersects(wallRect))
{
    // Player has hit the wall. Now to find out which direction it has come from

    if (oldRect.Center.X < wallRect.Center.X)
    {
        // Player came from left of wall
    }
    else
    {
        // Player came from right of wall
    }
}
```

Try this for a template and work your game logic into it.